# Is it possible to get Information about Chromecast device from receiver app

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am developing an app for Chromecast and I need something specific about that particular device. (MAC Address, ID, something like that) in order to generate an unique deviceID.

I need to access the information from the receiver app.

If it's not possible, how can I generate the same unique deviceID at startup?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API on the receiver to return the MAC address or any other unique identifier; you need to create and manage that yourself.